# Getting custom taxonomy tags based on get_the_ID() (Outside for loop)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy called `type`. Type has the following options:

- Blog
- News
- Training

I've created a draggable element (in Visual Composer) which will show these tags. Because of this, the draggable element is not part of `archive-resources.php`, so I can't run it through a loop.

What I'm trying to do is:

- Get blog post ID (which I've done via `get_the_ID()`.
- Display `type` that is assigned that blog post.

However, currently, all three `type` tags are displaying. Where am I going wrong?

```
$blogpostID = get_the_ID();
$termType = get_terms('type');
$output = '';

foreach ( $termType as $termT ) {
    echo $output . '<a href="'.get_term_link($termT).'">'.$termT->name.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: you could probably get the taxonomy of the post, then cross check `$termT` in the iteration with all the terms, an if statement should suffice

Comment: You can get the terms related to the post using `wp_get_post_terms()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok, Do it this way :**

```
<?php  
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'type' );
$output = '';
if ( $terms != null ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $output . '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
    }
}
```